# How to implement an props interface for conditions with styled components in React with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

This is a component written in React with the library "styled components" that handles user input. If the input of the user is invalid, the respective styles shown below should be displyed (class invalid). The example works with JavaScript perfectly. However, with TypeScript, I cannot get the props interface to work. As a workaround, I inserted `<any>` for `styled.div<any>`, which solves the error but, of course, defeats the purpose of TypeScript. The error output is shown after the code.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import styled from 'styled-components';
import Button from "../../UI/Button/Button";

const FormControl = styled.div<any>`
&.invalid label {
  color: red
}
&.invalid input {
  border-color: red;
  background: salmon;
}
`;

interface onAddGoalProps {
  onAddGoal: (enteredValue: string) => void;
}

const CourseInput: React.FC<onAddGoalProps> = ({ onAddGoal }) => {
  const [enteredValue, setEnteredValue] = useState("");
  const [isValid, setIsValid] = useState(true);

  const goalInputChangeHandler = (event: any) => {
    if (event.target.value.trim().length > 0) {
      setIsValid(true);
    }
    setEnteredValue(event.target.value);
  };

  const formSubmitHandler = (event: any) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (enteredValue.trim().length === 0) {
      setIsValid(false);
      return;
    }
    onAddGoal(enteredValue);
    setEnteredValue("");
    setIsValid(true);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={formSubmitHandler}>
      <FormControl className={isValid && 'invalid'}>
        <label>Course Goal</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          onChange={goalInputChangeHandler}
          value={enteredValue}
        />
      </FormControl>
      <Button type="submit">Add Goal</Button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default CourseInput;
```

Here the error ouput:

```
C:/Users/stroebele/dev/training/repositories/React-Library/3_advanced/app_tasks-manager/src/components/CourseGoals/CourseInput/CourseInput.tsx
  TypeScript error in C:/Users/stroebele/dev/training/repositories/React-Library/3_advanced/app_tasks-manager/src/components/CourseGoals/CourseInput/CourseInput.tsx(72,20):
  No overload matches this call.
    Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Omit<Omit<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>, "key" | keyof HTMLAttributes<...>> & { ...; }, never> & Partial<...>, "theme"> & { ...; } & { ...; }): ReactElement<...>', gave the following error.        
      Type 'false | "invalid"' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.
        Type 'false' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.
    Overload 2 of 2, '(props: StyledComponentPropsWithAs<"div", any, {}, never, "div">): ReactElement<StyledComponentPropsWithAs<"div", any, {}, never, "div">, string | JSXElementConstructor<...>>', gave the following error.
      Type 'false | "invalid"' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.  TS2769
  
      70 |       {/* because the styles are already attached via "styles components" */}
      71 |       {/* The case for " */}
    > 72 |       <FormControl className={isValid && 'invalid'}>
         |                    ^
      73 |         <label>Course Goal</label>
      74 |         <input
      75 |           type="text"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use this condition inside a `` `${}` ``

```js
<FormControl className={`${!isValid && 'invalid'}`}>
```

The issue here is that when `isValid` is true, a string 'false' will be compiled in the HTML, looking like this:

```html
<div class='false'>
```

An workaround for this is to set the classname like this:

```
<FormControl className={`${(!isValid && "invalid") || ""}`}>
```

Another solution would be use a ternary conditional:

```js
className={isValid ? '' : "invalid"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it. Pass the props, declare the type, and conditionally style.

```
 const FormControl = styled.div<{invalid?: boolean}>`
  ${p => p.invalid && `
    input {
      border-color: red;
      background: salmon;
    }

    label {
      color: red
    }
  `}
`;

 <FormControl invalid={!isValid}>children</FormControl>
```